# Как вручную вызвать View Controller? (Storyboard)

Tags: objective-c, ios7, controller

Есть два View контроллера, на одном просто красивая картинка, что бы когда приложение загружалось, люди видели картинку, а на другом Navigation контроллер всем заправляет. На сторибордах стрелочка стоит с первого контроллера (с картинкой который).

Собственно вопрос такой, как в коде вызвать контроллер?

Comment: Эта картинка нужна только как экран ожидания пока приложение грузится? А на нем что-то происходит?

Comment: Даа, просто что бы красиво было, там больше ничего нету, все действия начинаются со второго контроллера, на который я хочу перейти

Comment: Но есть такая штука как Default.png. iPhone/iPad загружает эту картинку автоматически как только стартует аппликация. Ничего не нужно делать. И эта картинка автоматически исчезает, как только  первый экран готов к работе! Или я чего-то не понял?

Comment: Кстати да, что-то не подумал даже о таком. Скажите, а всё таки, контроллер можно как-то вызвать в коде?

Comment: Да. Делаете инициализацию контроллера  и делаете с ним что хотите.

Comment: А можно какой-то код, или как это сделать, а то я не давно начал изучать программирование, и вот учу и сразу стараюсь сделать не большую программку)

Comment: @leonid3452 дружеский совет! Не поленитесь, скачайте книгу, поищите туториалы в инете по програмированию на Objective-C, iOS. Это Вам поможет больше, чем любой код, который кто-либо здесь напишет. Я это говорю не потому что мне лень или не хочется написать этот несчастный кусок кода, а потому что я за то, чтобы научить человека ловить рыбу, а не давать по рыбине, каждый раз когда ему кушать захочется. Важно понимать, что Вы делаете! А иначе вы будете создавать не программы, а сборные солянки, в которых сам черт ногу сломит.

Comment: Посмотрите на вот эту статью, возможно вам подойдёт http://avdyushin.ru/ios-launch-image/.